# c# - Assert Expressions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have an 'Example' class and I would like to create unit test for it. Take a look on my classes below:

```
public class Example 
{
    private readonly Calculator _calculator;

    public Example(ICalculator calculator)
    {
        _calculator = calculator;
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        _calculator.Execute(operation => operation.Subtract());
    }
}

public interface IOperation { 
    void Sum();
    void Subtract();
}

public inferface ICalculator { 
    void Execute(Action<IOperation> action);
}

public class Calculator {
    public void Execute(Action<IOperation> action){}
}
```

What I want is to create a Unit Test class to verify that my method from Example class `Calculate` calls the `_calculator.Execute` passing as parameter the `operation.Subtract()`. Is it possible?

I know how to mock my ICalculator and verify that `Execute` is being called once, but I have no idea how to validade if `Execute` method was called using `operation.Subtract()` as parameter instead of `operation.Sum()`.

I am using `NUnit` to create my unit tests. Here you can see how my unit test class is at the moment:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExampleTests 
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var calculator = new Mock<ICalculator>();
        var subject = new Example(calculator.Object);

        subject.Calculate();

        calculator.Verify(x => x.Execute(It.IsAny<Action<IOperation>>()), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Hope someone can understand my english, sorry about that.

Comment: What is your Subtract() method does share that code?

Comment: Currently your method has no return value nor any known observable side effects, therefore there is nothing to test.  It either needs to return some value that you can verify is correct, or make some change that you can observe.  
As soon as your method actually does something, you can test that it does that something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly verify what lambda was passed but you can go around it by *actually invoking* said lambda with yet another mock:

```
var calculator = new Mock<ICalculator>();
var operation = new Mock<IOperation>();
// when calculator's Execute is called, invoke it's argument (Action<IOperation>)
// with mocked IOperation which will later be verified
calculator
    .Setup(c => c.Execute(It.IsAny<Action<IOperation>>()))
    .Callback<Action<IOperation>>(args => args(operation.Object));
var example = new Example(calculator.Object);

example.Calculate();

calculator.Verify(c => c.Execute(It.IsAny<Action<IOperation>>()));
operation.Verify(o => o.Subtract());
```

Comment: I am sorry for never had given you a feedback. Your solution was exactly what I was looking for at that time. Also I have used your solution many times during this Year (2015). You saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing anonymous delegate `operation => operation.Subtract()` to `_calculator.Execute` - so you cannot construct it later when asserting for argument.

You can get around it by doing this:

```
    public class Example 
    {
        private readonly ICalculator _calculator;

        public Example(ICalculator calculator)
        {
            _calculator = calculator;
        }

        public Action<IOperation> Subtract = op => op.Subtract();

        public Action<IOperation> Add = op => op.Sum();

        public void Calculate()
        {
            _calculator.Execute(Subtract);
        }
    }
```

And asserting like this (ommiting 2nd param defaults to Once):

```
calculator.Verify(x => x.Execute(subject.Subtract));
```

However this looks like convoluted design in order to be able to write a test.